# Drawable folder and java classes are all red?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I opened my project today and all I saw is red color. My java classes are red , all the code inside a class is red. Also my drawable folder is red and inside of them everything is disorganised. Also my build.gradle is disorganised [Look at the pic below] and red. I tried Invalidate , deletet vsc from folder , deletet .idea and .gradle but nothing is working.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may have confused something (copy-past to the wrong file).

As I can see from the screenshot, your Gradle file contains the code from Resources. Most likely, if you restore the Gradle file to its original state, all errors will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I enabled vcs and disabled it again. Somehow it solved the build.gradle file. Than to go back to normal , I just deletet the cache file inside the android studio 4.0 folder.